# Send data to header template file

Tags: template, controllers

I want to send some data to header block from a controller. Tried this way. But its not working.

```
<?php
class Mageart_Iosapi_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    { 
        $data = "testing";
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("header")->setData("isodata", $data);   
        $this->loadLayout();                
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Please Wait.."));
        $this->renderLayout(); 
        $templateImage = $this->getRequest()->getPost('template_image');
        $productId     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        $firstname     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('firstname');
        $lastname     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('lastname');
        $cusemail     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('cusemail');
        $password     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        $qty           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('qty');

        $arg = array(
            'template_image' => bin2hex($templateImage),
            'product_id' => bin2hex($productId),
            'firstname' => bin2hex($firstname),
            'lastname' => bin2hex($lastname),
            'cusemail' => bin2hex($cusemail),
            'password' => bin2hex($password),
            'qty' => bin2hex($qty)            
        );


        if ( (isset($firstname) || $firstname != "") && (isset($lastname) || $lastname != "")
                && (isset($cusemail) || $cusemail != "") && (isset($password) || $password != "") ) {
             $customer = $this->_loadCustomer($firstname, $lastname, $cusemail, $password);
             $this->_redirect('iosapi/index/addtocart',$arg);
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Customer Details are Missing.');
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            $errorStatus = false;

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In header.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getData("isodata"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to load the layout

```
class Mageart_Iosapi_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    { 
        $data = "testing";   
        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("header")->setData("data", $data); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using a less arbitrary name than `data` since it might cause conflicts. Try `isodata` for example.

Comment: Thank you. But its still not giving any output. I have updated the question.

Comment: Since you're redirecting to another page at the end of the controller method this would cause the page not to be rendered

Comment: Can you please suggest any alternative method, when its redirect and still way to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('header')
     ->setIsodata($data);

<?php echo $this->getIsodata();?>
```